# Laravel Project Structure with Subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I have started a laravel project called `webdev`. I want this project to have subdomains, however, i do not know how to do so. I tried looking around and couldn't find an explanation on how to structure my project so I can use a subdomain.

Right now this is what I've done:

In `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/project/` I created the main for `webdev` with `laravel new webdev`. This is where I want to have the main site. But now I want to have a subdomain for `webdev` which handles all the account processing. So how do I create the subdomain for this? Do I do `laravel new accounts` in `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/project/` then how do I tell `webdev` that `accounts` is a subdomain?

Comment: Laravel 3 or 4? Also did you try adding it to the routes file?

Comment: @etr laravel 4. I'm trying to understand how the directory structure should work if I want to have subdomains.

Comment: @Vanessa i guess you don't need special directory structure routes will handle it for you http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing

Comment: @Humanlove but can the subdomain of `webdev` be a laravel project such as `laravel new subdomain_name` in the same directory as `webdev` is?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on subdomain wildcards and point them to your main app document root. Laravel routes handle wildcard sub-domains, and pass you wildcard parameters from the domain.

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.yourdomain.com'), function()
{

    Route::get('user/{id}', function($account, $id)
    {
        //
    });

});
```

Also see [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing) for this.